# Create a new data frame in R containing statistics of another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, aggregate, summary

I need to create a new data frame containing statistics from another data frame, but I don't know how to do it. The data frame I have is called 'day' and the data frame I created and I want to complete is called 'stats'.

I tried with summary and aggregate, but I don't arrive to the result I want.

```
stats <- data.frame("Place"=NA, "Mean"=NA, "Min"=NA, "Max"=NA, "sd"=NA)
summary(substet(day, cd="2A", select=price))
try <- aggregate(price~dep, day, mean)
```

My data frame 'day' :

```
day         carb      dep     cd price  p1      p2     p3     p4

02/03/2019  Gasoline  HR      NA 1440   place1  NA     NA      NA
03/03/2019  Gasoline  Corsica 2A 1445   NA      NA     NA      NA
```

So I have 25 places at the total, and I want to do something like that : if dep=="Corsica" and carb=="gasoline", then obtain the data frame "stats" like this :

```
Place   Mean   Min     Max     sd
Corsica value  value   value   value
```

The idea is to complete gradually this data frame with the values for the other 24 places.

I hope that you'll understand what I want to say, I'm sorry but I am a true beginner.

Comment: ```df %>% group_by(carb, dep) %>% summarise_all(c(mean, min, max, sd))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple with dplyr with the following code.

```
library(dplyr)
stats <- day %>% 
    group_by(dep, carb) %>% 
    summarize(mean=mean(price, na.rm = T), 
              min=min(price, na.rm = T), 
              max=max(price, na.rm = T), 
              sd=sd(price, na.rm = T))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I have NAs everywhere in the data frame I create with your code.

Comment: @Noah You need to load `dplyr` as you are using `%>%` piping!

Comment: @M-M is correct answer amended based on the comment above.

Comment: @marie_mrc because the data has NAs you need to add ```na.rm = T``` in the summary functions. Changing the answer to reflect this.

Comment: I did it but it just added a column named "na.rm" filled with "TRUE". It just worked for one place, with or without this command.

Comment: ``` library(dplyr), stats <- day %>% , group_by(dep, carb) %>%, summarize(mean=mean(price), min=min(price), max=max(price), sd=sd(price), na.rm = T) ``` I also tried with dplyr:: but the result is the same.

Comment: The following code produced exactly you're desired output when I ran your code. ```stats <- day %>% 
  group_by(dep, carb) %>%
  summarize(mean=mean(price, na.rm = T),
          min=min(price, na.rm = T),
          max=max(price, na.rm = T), sd=sd(price, na.rm = T))```

Comment: And do you know how to group_by a place and carb, if the place is like a string dummy ? Because i created day$place3 <- NA,  day$place3 with(day, day$dep = "HR" & day$type="GMS" & is.na(day$place3)) <- "HR_GMS" but when I want to group_by with this column, I have 4 observations (2 NA and 2 HR_GMS), but I want only 2 (HR_GMS)